# Big O или О-нотация

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

Прохожу курс Python-разработчика. В общем и целом я понял, что такое О-нотация, система оценок... но вот столкнулся с проблемой. В курсе есть наглядная таблица и некоторое описание [image: Таблица Big O] пока вроде все понятно. но следующий вопрос поставил в тупик.

> Задача: Во сколько раз (примерно) возрастет время работы алгоритма
> сложностью O(n^2) по сравнению с O(n*log(n)) на входных данных размера
> n=10000? Ответ округлите до целого. Помните также, что логарифм
> берется по основанию 2.

Я пробовал посчитать разницу межу n*n и log(n). пробовал сделать как в задании (n*log(n)) и еще всяческий делать вычисления между этими 2умя сложностями алгоритма. Помогите разобраться пж

Comment: Если брать на логику, то не думаю что надо будет считать квадрат 10.000. Тогда просто берем и упрощаем каждый алгоритм на n итераций и тогда ищем O(n) / O(log(n)) = 752.57

Comment: Спасибо большое!. да, действительно. если математический упростить выражение - получим правильный ответ.

Comment: @entithat а чего не ответом?

Comment: @tym32167, не хотел отвечать предположением :)